# Using lapply function within another one avoiding list of lists

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply, nested-lists

Supposing an example in R where we use the `lapply` function within a same function to create an one-level list:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x)
{
  r <- sample(4,1)

  i<-lapply(1:r, function (y)
  {
    matrix(rep(1*x*y,3))
  })
  i
})
```

The given result is a two-level list (list of lists) like this one:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    2
[3,]    2

[[2]][[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    4
[2,]    4
[3,]    4

[[2]][[3]]
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    6
[3,]    6

[[2]][[4]]
     [,1]
[1,]    8
[2,]    8
[3,]    8


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3
[3,]    3

[[3]][[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    6
[3,]    6


# ...
```

Preserving both `lapply` functions (or similar ones) and matrices **with equal dimensions**, how we could get an one-level list thus?

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    2
[3,]    2

[[3]]
     [,1]
[1,]    4
[2,]    4
[3,]    4

# ...
```

Comment: `lapply` always returns a `list`. (That's what the **l** in the name stands for.) Use `sapply` instead to **s**implify.

Comment: If `j` is the object returned by your code, you may try `unlist(j,recursive=FALSE)`.

Comment: @Gregor, your suggestion doen't keep matrices with the same dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the second `lapply` with `sapply` and include the argument `simplify = TRUE`

Comment: `simplify = TRUE` is the default for `sapply`, you don't need to include it. And to make this a better answer you should show the full code. (I'm not sure this actually duplicates OP's desired output).

Comment: I think that pushes all those nested 1-column matrices in to a wider matrix.  I think OP wanted to keep the matrices separate, but just  reducing the nesting layers.

Comment: That change doesn't preserve the dimensions of the matrices, like @wibeasley said.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how [purrr](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html) can best accommodate matrices inside a list.  The concluding [`flatten()`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/flatten.html) line is the equivalent of @nicola's suggestion to use [`unlist(., recursive=F)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html).

```
library(magrittr)
purrr::map(1:5, function(x) {
  r <- sample(4,1)

  purrr::map(1:r, function(y) {
    matrix(rep(1*x*y,3))
  }) 
}) %>% 
purrr::flatten() #This line is the equivalent of nicola's `unlist()`
```